# Way to force text to wrap in browser even when it is a consecutive string with no spaces?

Tags: html, css

If I have a string like `"11111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110"`

How can I get this string in my page to wrap? Here (stackoverflow) they do it.

Currently on my page it just displays on one line and flows way to the right ?

Comment: What browser are you using?  Do you have any CSS or HTML formatting, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a `word-wrap:break-word`:

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word;">LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG</pre>
```

Or:

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapit{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
<div class="wrapit">LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG</div>
```

Comment: This only works on IE though.  word-wrap is not offically part of CSS, AFAIK.

Comment: It's not part of CSS2, but [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110215/#word-wrap). Not sure why this got a -1 vote, would you recommend something else?