# Why is this simple CSS div not working?

Tags: css, html, overflow, hidden

I have a div. It is really simple. Here is the CSS code below.

```
#example {
    background: #dcdcdc;
    background-position: center;
    postition: relative;
    width: 980px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 1px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="example">testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest</div>
```

As you can see it only contains text that is selected from a database table.
The problem is that when the length of the text is wider than the screen it does not start a new line, it goes over. I want to make it start a new line. How could I do that?

Note: The overflow is hidden on the page. I only tested this page in Chrome 13 and FF 3.6.

Comment: You need to add `word-wrap: break-word;`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569367/way-to-force-text-to-wrap-in-browser-even-when-it-is-a-consecutive-string-with-no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word wrap will do the trick:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 5):

**multi browser answer :**

add this :

```
word-break: break-all;
white-space:normal;
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Multi-browser? All modern browsers support `word-wrap`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap#Browser_compatibility

Comment: to my experience - there were some problems with it : http://www.homesecurityitem.com/post/109.html

Answer (score 4):

Add `word-wrap: break-word;` into that mix.